# Relative layout put view infront of other views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have a `CalendarView` which will open when a button is clicked. But once it is open the view is behind all the other buttons. I need a way so it is in front of all the buttons except the one which opens the calendar.

The view:

[image: My view:]

The calendar opens with the click of the left bottom button. So only that button will be infront of the calendar.

My XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="example.test.sliderappv002.MainActivity">



<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:transitionGroup="false" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/container"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"/>


<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calenderView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/fab"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/fab"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/fab"
    android:scaleX="0.9"
    android:scaleY="0.9"
    android:minDate="01/01/2016"
    android:maxDate="12/31/2016"
    android:background="@color/DarkGray">
</CalendarView>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fab"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/container"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fab2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/container"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame" />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fab3"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/container"
    android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:focusable="false" />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/fab4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fab3"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:focusable="false" />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/fab3"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
    android:focusable="false" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Floating buttons are designed to float on the top of all other views, so you can't put any other view on top of them. In addition i think you shouldn't use 6 FloatingActionButtons in your layout. UI guidelines are strongly discouraging this kind of approach.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try moving the CalendarView down in the order?
Since it's a RelativeLayout I think that should do the trick.

```
<RelativeLayout ...>

... this is behind ...

<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calenderView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/fab"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/fab"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/fab"
    android:scaleX="0.9"
    android:scaleY="0.9"
    android:minDate="01/01/2016"
    android:maxDate="12/31/2016"
    android:background="@color/DarkGray">
</CalendarView>

... this is in front ...

</RelativeLayout>
```